Populating alt text when uploading image
In CKEditor 4, I've got these plugins loaded: image,...,uploadwidget,uploadimage
Say I've got an image 'good-description-for-seo.webp' which I drag onto the editor. Currently, the alt tag is blank and I need to type in
"good description for seo"
So I'm looking for a way to populate the alt text after tweaking the image filename a bit.
I dug around in /plugins/image/dialogs/image.js which looked promising, especially the line
this.setValue(b.getAttribute("alt"))
but any tweaks I made in there didn't seem to make any difference to the alt tag field in the image dialog box.
How can I populate the alt text field based on the image file name?
